# Auto Script To Clear Sheet After Idle Or Last Input

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm totally noob in scripting
I want to ask is there a script to auto clear Sheet in Google Sheet after 30 minutes of idle or 30 minutes after the last input has been made, but the time duration is still editable for future use
Thank you very much

The sheet will automatically cleared after certain amount of time

Comment: You could probably do it with an installable onEdit() trigger by creating a time back trigger that runs sheet.clearContents()

Answer (score 1):

**A function that deletes all previous triggers with same handler name and sets a new one 30 minutes from current time**

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() != 'Your sheet name' ) return;
  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "clearMySheetContents()").forEach(t => ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(t));
  let dt = new Date();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("clearMySheetContents").timeBased().after(1800000);
}

function clearMySheetContents() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Your sheet name");
  sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,sh.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
}
```

"If you wish to view the onEdit event object try this:

```
function onMyEdit(e){Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))};
//{""authMode"":""FULL"",""oldValue"":""10.0"",""range"":{""columnEnd"":6,""columnStart"":6,""rowEnd"":6,""rowStart"":6},""source"":{},""triggerUid"":"""",""user"":{""email"":"""",""nickname"":""""},""value"":""""}
```

You cannot run the onEdit functions without supplying the event object. If you attempt to run from the script editor without supplying the event object you will get an error.  The onEdit trigger is a simple trigger meaning that it cannot perform functions that require permission.  If you need to perform commands that require permission you must create an installable trigger either programmatically or through the editors trigger panel.

There are several limitations running scripts this way.  You will have difficulty using alert and prompt boxes.  They are fairly difficult to debug because the onEdit is not easily run in debug mode so you are left having to edit the appropriate elements on the desired sheet."

Note: I have not tested this onEdit function.

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [onEdit.restrictions()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)

Comment: Sorry, finally got it to worked. Thank you. But if I want to delete starting from certain range, where should I edit the scipts.
Like the first row is for the headers, so I want to clear eveything from 2nd row downward